# How to prevent 'UnhandledPromiseRejection' on wrong user input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async.js

I have 2 file, main.js and input.js. 
In input.js I prompt the user to give me an interval in '1-10'(string) format. Later I cut this string and get the 2 numbers from it and check if the numbers are correct or not:

```
let getInput = () => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    readline.question(`Give me interval (e.g.: 1-10).\n`, (input) => {
      let fields = input.split('-');
      let startNumber = Number(fields[0]);
      let endNumber = Number(fields[1]);
      if ((startNumber) && (endNumber) && (startNumber > 0) && (endNumber >= startNumber)) {
        console.log(`ok`);
        readline.close()
        resolve([startNumber, endNumber]);
      } else {
        reject('not ok');
        getInput();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

In main.js I call this function asyncronously and I save it's result to a variable:

```
let intervalArray = await getInput();
.
.
.
someotherstuff
```

My problem is if I provide wrong input (for example '0-1' or '10-9' or '-10')
I got an UnhandledPromise error so the code won't execute more. 
My goal would be when the user gives wrong input, 'not ok, give me another' should appear in console, and the program should wait for another input. If that input is correct, continue the execution. If not, the program should ask another input.

How could I achieve this?

**EDIT:** 
Here are the full codes. 
Input.js:

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

let getInput = () => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    readline.question(`tol-ig formatumban (pl.: 1-10).\n`, (data) => {
      let fields = data.split('-');
      let startNumber = Number(fields[0]);
      let endNumber = Number(fields[1]);
      if ((startNumber) && (endNumber) && (startNumber > 0) && (endNumber >= startNumber)) {
        console.log(`Kereses inditasa ${startNumber}-${endNumber} oldalakon.`);
        readline.close()
        resolve([startNumber, endNumber]);
      } else {
        readline.close();
        reject(new Error('not ok'));
      }
    });
  });
}

module.exports.getInput = getInput;
```

And main.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { getInput } = require('./input');
const { mouseMovements } = require('./mouse');
const { tuneUserAgent } = require('./userAgent');

async function listItems() {
  let intervalArray = null;
  while (intervalArray === null) {
    try {
      let intervalArray = await getInput();
    } catch (err) {
      // write to user not ok
    }
  }
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  const extractPartners = async url => {
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await tuneUserAgent(page);

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load' });
    await page.waitFor(Math.round(Math.random() * 500) + 500);

    await mouseMovements(page);

    const partnersOnPage = await page.evaluate(() =>
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.compact"))
        .map(compact => (compact.querySelector(".logo a").href.slice(-16))));
    await page.close();

    const nextPageNumber = parseInt(url.match(/page=(\d+)$/)[1], 10) + 1;
    if (nextPageNumber > endPage) {
      console.log(`Terminate recursion on: ${url}`);
      return partnersOnPage;
    } else {
      console.log(`Scraped: ${url}`);
      const nextUrl = `https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/partners/find-a-partner?page=${nextPageNumber}`;
      let randomWait = (Math.round(Math.random() * 2000) + 1000);
      await page.waitFor(randomWait);
      return partnersOnPage.concat(await extractPartners(nextUrl));
    }
  };
  let startPage = intervalArray[0];
  let endPage = intervalArray[1];
  const firstUrl =
    `https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/partners/find-a-partner?page=${startPage}`;
  const partners = await extractPartners(firstUrl);
  await browser.close();
  return Promise.resolve(partners);
};

module.exports.listItems = listItems;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle the error. As you are using await, the easiest is to use try catch.

```
try {
  let intervalArray = await getInput();
} catch (err) {
  // write to user not ok
}
```

You can wrap it in cycle to keep requesting user for new inputs.

```
let intervalArray = null;
while (intervalArray === null) {
    try {
      let intervalArray = await getInput();
    } catch (err) {
      // write to user not ok
    }
}
```

^^ Remember to remove `getInput();` from the `else` part of your new Promise. Maybe you will also need to close the readline as you will open it again. Also rejection is similar to throwing an error and you should always send Error-based object there.

```
  } else {
    readline.close();
    reject(new Error('not ok'));
  }
```

---

EDIT: after your update I created POC. The `readline.close()` should not be there actually (looks its one time use only), but this POC looks fine:

`toBeRequired.js`

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let getInput = () => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        readline.question(`tol-ig formatumban (pl.: 1-10).\n`, (data) => {
            let fields = data.split('-');
            let startNumber = Number(fields[0]);
            let endNumber = Number(fields[1]);
            if ((startNumber) && (endNumber) && (startNumber > 0) && (endNumber >= startNumber)) {
                console.log(`Kereses inditasa ${startNumber}-${endNumber} oldalakon.`);
                readline.close()
                resolve([startNumber, endNumber]);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('not ok'));
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getInput = getInput;
```

`server.js`

```
const a = require('./toBeRequired');

async function x() {
  let input = null;
  while (input === null) {
    try {
      input = await a.getInput();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('nooo');
    }
  }
}

x();
```

Create these two files in same folder and run `node server.js`

Comment: I've updated my code with your solution, but it's the same; in case of wrong input, I got Promise error and the execution stops.

Comment: @ConTroll - then update your question with full solution that you have now, there is probably some other error you dont know about.

Comment: @ConTroll - maybe its different error now. You can start from my POC and then keep adding stuff. Also you should see error stacktrace that should tell you where is the error and what is the cause.